# The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object xp_availablemedia

Tags: sql-server

One of my colleagues has `Public` role on SQL Management Studio but `db_owner` on a couple of DB. While trying to CREATE back-up, the following message pops up

[image: Error while taking back-up]

I have now added db_backupoperator on the DB, still the following error

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the user has enough permissions to perform a backup, but not enough permissions to enumerate the filesystem on the server, which is what SSMS does behind the scenes.

This behaviour is described in this [support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323249), which suggests adding the login to the sysadmin role.

To work around it, add a backup device with [sp_addumpdevice](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188409(v=sql.120).aspx) and let the user backup to that device.

Comment: the main idea was not to give the sysadmin and only let the user manage own databases..i have now added the user to sysadmin but now the user has all the privilages on all the databases

Comment: let me put the question in another way then: can i create a role that includes sysadmin privilages ona few databases and assign it to a user?

Comment: @itsAftab nope. Sysadmin is all or nothing. Have you tried with a backup device as suggested?

Comment: i considered it but have opted not to use it...thank you for the advice though :)

Comment: @itsAftab Could you explain why?

Comment: @AaronBertrand sorry if i came out rude..firstly i didnt quite understood the whole procedure :( and then i didn't want to mess up the premissions

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It should be obvious but substitute your login and user names for what's below.

```
use master
grant view server state to [loginName]
alter server role dbcreator add member [loginName]
create user [userName] for login [loginName]
alter role db_owner add member [userName]
```